# How to use Webform values in Rules?

Tags: 7, webforms, rules

I am using the **[Webform Rules](https://drupal.org/project/webform_rules)** module and I created an event '*After submitting webform*', and an action '*Fetch webform submissions*'.

When I add an action '*Show a message on the site*', I get all the webform data values and I can print them out in status message.

Now I want to **Get the user ID who submitted the webform** to send that user a private message (about the form data). But when I add an action '*Fetch entity by ID*', I get no webform data values there (I'd like to use a data value as entity ID).

Am I missing something, is this the right way to achieve this ? Any other idea on how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module is indeed part of the puzzle to answer your question, as you can read also on its project page:

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.
>
> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but couldn't find the proper event?
>
> Webform Rules makes it possible to catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

#### 1. Get the user ID who submitted the webform

Have a look at this example rule (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_process_submitted_webform" : {
    "LABEL" : "Process submitted webform",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "webform_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[site:mail]",
          "subject" : "A new webform submission has occured",
          "message" : "A new webform submission has occured (with form-id \u0022[form-id:value]\u0022). It was submitted by the user with id = [user:id], name = [user:name] and eMail Id = [user:mail] ...",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I intentionally did not include any Rules Conditions here, just to illustrate that by using the Rules Event you're already using, you do have access to a limited set of tokens related to the user who submitted the webform, such as `[user:id]`, `[user:name]` and `[user:mail]`. In other words, you don't need a Rules Action like "*fetch entity by ID*" for these kinds of tokens to be available.

Of course, because of the nature of your question, you may want to add a Rules Condition to check that the user is not an anonymous user.

#### 2. About the Webform data

The "Webform data"-part of your question seems like an example (variation?) of what's asked for in the feature request "[Expose submission data to rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2020149)". Here is a summary of it:

> Right now, submission data is not exposed to rules except by way of token replacement or custom php actions. This patch exposes submission data in a "first-class" way.

Issue status is "Needs work" ... not an "easy" issue though.

The very same issue contains a [comment with a workaround](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules/issues/2020149#comment-12205966) (it's genious I think, because it's so simple), here is a relevant quote from it:

> You can initialize a rules string variable with the tokens. If you need integers or booleans you can subsequently convert it to whatever and then use it to load nodes or whatever.

A picture is worth more then 1000 words: checkout the [screenprint included in that comment](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/exposed_submission_workaround.png).

So you could use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How to do a data comparison to submitted webform data when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable`, with a value assigned to it equal to your Webform data you want to use (and with an appropriate data type). You'd need 1 such variable for each Webform component for which you want to access its Webform data.
- In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of these variables you just added (that's the clue!).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.